# Where does Mac OS X store folder association information

Tags: macos, finder

I am having a strange problem on MAC OS X.

Whenever I open a folder from LaunchBar like `Download` or from the terminal using `open .` it opens my DVD player! Hover I do not have any DVD drive :( The only solution what I found is to uninstall DVD player. So I can open my folders normally.

Would you know some of you where Mac stores **FOLDER** association (it is not file association)?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this happen for a specific folder only? Or all folders? And when you uninstall the DVD Player app, it returns to opening folders with Finder?

Comment: It happens with all folders. When I uninstall DVD Player (which get's back every time there is a new OS release), then folders are opened correctly with Finder.

Comment: Interesting… Maybe you can check with [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) what DVD Player is associated with.